# Polymer Firebase: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, polymer

I am trying to insert data to firebase in Polymer; using polymerfire.

When I am clicking the button to add data nothing happening. In console this error is showing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Here is my code: "my-ask.html"

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<link rel="import" href="my-fab.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-textarea.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-query.html">
<dom-module id="my-ask">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
      }


  paper-input, paper-textarea {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  iron-icon, div[suffix] {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 50%);
    margin-right: 12px;
  }


  paper-dropdown-menu, paper-listbox {
    width: 250px;

  }
  paper-dropdown-menu {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }


  paper-button {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

  paper-button.green {
    background-color: var(--paper-green-500);
    color: white;
  }
  paper-button.green[active] {
    background-color: var(--paper-red-500);
  }
    </style>

      <firebase-auth 
            user="{{user}}">
      </firebase-auth>
      <firebase-query
          id="query"
          app-name="lore"
          path="/users/[[user.uid]]/questions"
          data="{{questions}}"
          ></firebase-query>

    <div id="card">
      <div id="questions">
        <ul id="questions-list">
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[questions]]" as="question">
            <li>
              <p class="content">[[question.content]]</p>
            </li>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <template is="dom-if" if="[[user]]">
    <div class="card">
      <h1>Ask a Question [[user.uid]] :</h1>


      <paper-input label="Title of your Question" id="qbody"></paper-input>

      <paper-textarea label="Your Question in details"  value=""></paper-textarea>

      <paper-dropdown-menu label="Select a Category">
        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
          <paper-item>allosaurus</paper-item>
          <paper-item>brontosaurus</paper-item>
          <paper-item>carcharodontosaurus</paper-item>
          <paper-item>diplodocus</paper-item>
        </paper-listbox>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>

      <paper-input label="Tags (Setarate with (,) Comma)"></paper-input>

      <paper-button raised>Cancel</paper-button>
      <paper-button raised class="green" style="float:right" id="add" on-tap="add">Ask</paper-button>

      <paper-input label="username">
        <iron-icon icon="mail" prefix></iron-icon>
        <div suffix>@email.com</div>
      </paper-input>


    </div>
    </template>

    <template is="dom-if" if="[[!user]]">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">2</div>
      <h1>Hello unknown user</h1>
      <p>Ut labores minimum atomorum pro. Laudem tibique ut has.</p>
      <p>Lorem</p>
    </div>
    </template>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-ask',
      properties: {
        uid: String,
        questions: {
          type: Object
        }
      },

      add: function() {
        this.$.query.ref.push({
          content: this.$.qbody.value
        });
        this.$.qbody.value = null;
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

And this is  tag code in "my-app.html"

```
<firebase-app
  id="lore-970d3"
  auth-domain="lore-970d3.firebaseapp.com"
  database-url="https://lore-970d3.firebaseio.com/"
  api-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  >
</firebase-app>
```

Full code of "my-app.html"

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-route.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">

<link rel="import" href="my-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-fab.html">
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --app-primary-color: #4285f4;
        --app-secondary-color: black;

        display: block;
      }

      app-header {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: var(--app-primary-color);
      }
      app-header paper-icon-button {
        --paper-icon-button-ink-color: white;
      }

      .drawer-list {
        margin: 0 20px;
      }

      .drawer-list a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: var(--app-secondary-color);
        line-height: 40px;
      }

      .drawer-list a.iron-selected {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>


    <firebase-app
      id="lore-970d3"
      auth-domain="lore-970d3.firebaseapp.com"
      database-url="https://lore-970d3.firebaseio.com"
      api-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      >
    </firebase-app>


    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/:page"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

    <app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
      <!-- Drawer content -->
      <app-drawer id="drawer">
        <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
        <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
          <a name="home" href="/home">Home</a>
          <a name="view1" href="/view1">View One</a>
          <a name="view2" href="/view2">View Two</a>
          <a name="view3" href="/view3">View Three</a>
        </iron-selector>
      </app-drawer>

      <!-- Main content -->
      <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

        <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div main-title>My App</div>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>
           <my-fab></my-fab>
        <iron-pages
            selected="{{page}}"
            attr-for-selected="name"
            fallback-selection="view404"
            role="main">
          <my-home name="home"></my-home>
          <my-ask name="ask"></my-ask>
          <my-profile name="profile"></my-profile>
          <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
          <my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
          <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
          <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
        </iron-pages>
      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-app',

      properties: {
        page: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          observer: '_pageChanged',
        },
      },

      observers: [
        '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)',
      ],

      _routePageChanged: function(page) {
        this.page = page || 'home';

        if (!this.$.drawer.persistent) {
          this.$.drawer.close();
        }
      },

      _pageChanged: function(page) {
        // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
        var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
        this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, null, this._showPage404, true);
      },

      _showPage404: function() {
        this.page = 'view404';
      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: is `polymerfire/polymerfire.html` imported in my-app.html ?

Comment: No, I had not imported `polymerfire/polymerfire.html` .But now when I am trying to import `polymerfire/polymerfire.html` I am getting white screen! @Parth

Comment: what's the error now ?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Polymer is not a function
    at firebase-app.html:21
    at firebase-app.html:126
polymer-micro.html:223`  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'instanceCount' of undefined
    at HTMLElement.__initialize (polymer-micro.html:223)
    at HTMLElement.createdCallback (polymer-micro.html:217)`

and ` Polymer is not a function` same error 6 more time

Comment: post your entire my-app.html .. its just sequence error.